# excel VBA: Filter out today's value from the table containing values for multiple dates and times

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, time

I have a table of data for certain date and time with date and time format as "dd/mm/yy hh:mm".
I want to highlight the cells with only today's date.
I have wrote the following program but it doesn't seem to work.

In my table of data, the dates are in row 5 starting from D column.

```
Sub SmplAnalFormat()
'
' SmplAnalFormat Macro
'

'

Dim i As Integer
i = 5

Dim dt1, dt2 As Date

Dim d1 As Double
Dim d2 As Double
Dim v As Double

dt1 = Date + 0 + TimeValue("00:00:01")
dt2 = Date + 1 + TimeValue("00:00:01")

d1 = dt1
d2 = dt2

ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Select

While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
v = ActiveCell.Value

    If d1 < v < d2 Then
    Debug.Print v; d1; d2; dt1; dt2; ActiveCell.Value
    
   ' Cells(5, i).Interior.ColorIndex =
   ' Else
   ' ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      End If
      Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
      i = i + 1
              
Wend

  '  Columns("D:R").Select
  '  Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

In the above code I am first converting all date and time to numeric value and then checking if they are between today morning to tonight midnight. But the condition is not working. I couldn't figure out why...

Comment: Correct (improve) with `Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date: dt1 = Date: dt2 = Date + 1: If v >= dt1 And v < dt2 Then`. The condition could be simplified with `If Int(v) = Date Then`.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation in this case is the following of this `d1 < v < d2`

First: `d1 < v` results a logical value 0 or 1.

Second: `(0 or 1) < d2`

You need logically `AND` two comparisons sg. like this:

```
    If d1 < v And v < d2 Then
```

Comment: Oh my god! This is perfect.
It works... Thanks a lot for quick response.